# TFS 2013 BuildAgent hanging while building solution

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild

We have a problem with the TFS build agent intermittently hanging while building our solution.  We have some custom build actions, we're using eazfuscator, and we have some post build actions as well.

So it's quite possible we are causing the problem.  We've identified that the solution (filled with C# projects) starts compiling but does not finish.  What we need is the log file from MSBuild/csc, but because the solution never finishes, those logs never go to the build drop.

I need help finding the log file on the build agent.  Any ideas?

Thanks!!

Comment: Do you have access to the build agent, enough to log in and check the build folder to see what is happening?

Comment: @d3r3kk - Yes, I can see the build agent.  I know that not all of the projects are getting built, but I can't find a log file.

Comment: Did you turn the log verbosity to high in your build definition before you queued a build?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to copy the MSBuild command which is generated in TFS build for code compilation, run the same command on build agent server manually from command prompt. Here, you will get more details to figure out the cause build for hanging issue.